# Get values (plural) from multi-dimensional array with key

Tags: php

I know the key, now I need **ALL** of the results that would yield when I search the 5000+ user database. Any user may have none, one or multiple locations, identified by an `id` and `name` field. Therefore I need the results in an array, not just the first/last one, but all of them. Below is an example of a user (actual array setup, fake data ;) )

```
Array
(
[ID] => 2
[user_login] => SomeGuy
[user_pass] => GreatEncryptedPassword
[user_nicename] => Some Guy
[user_email] => someguy@has-email.com
[user_url] => someguy.com
[user_registered] => 2013-04-11 11:18:58
[user_activation_key] => 
[user_status] => 0
[display_name] => Some Guy
[umeta_id] => 31
[user_id] => 2
[meta_key] => facebookmeta
[meta_value] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1234567890
        [name] => Some Guy
        [first_name] => Some
        [last_name] => Guy
        [link] => http://www.facebook.com/someguy
        [username] => someguy
        [birthday] => 02/21/1983
        [location] => Array
            (
                [id] => 108276092536515   //actual ID, try at facebook.com/108276092536515
                [name] => Arnhem, Netherlands
            )

        [gender] => male
        [relationship_status] => In a Relationship
        [significant_other] => Array
            (
                [name] => Some Chick
                [id] => 12345678906789
            )

        [email] => someguy@has-email.com
        [timezone] => 2
        [locale] => nl_NL
        [verified] => 1
        [updated_time] => 2013-04-02T09:28:30+0000
    )
)
```

As you can make out, this guy has 1 location in his facebook data, but other locations include the same `[location] => Array ( [id] => 123 [name] => SomePlace )` for example for `[work]` or `[education]`, or, or, or...

I've tried a recursive function like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4467135/1155833):

```
function get_value_by_key( $array, $key ){
    foreach( $array as $k => $each ){
        if( $k == $key ){
            return $each;
        }

        if( is_array( $each )){
            if( $return = get_value_by_key($each,$key)){
                return $return;
            }
        }
    }
}

print_r( get_value_by_key( $users, 'location' );
```

How can I modify the above function to return an array of location arrays? This one return the above data of the first user containing a location, not the location itself or an array of them.

**EDIT:**
What I need as a result is something like this:

```
Array(
    [0] => Array(
         [id] => 1234567890
         [name] => GreatCity, World
        )
    [1] => Array(
         [id] => 2345678901
         [name] => SomeCity, Blop
        )
    [2] => Array(
         [id] => 3456789012
         [name] => AnotherCity, Boo
        )
)
```

**Edit based on answer**
Answer from Thomas David Plat gives me the correct results, but still a not very usable data structure. How to get the results out of the structure and into that shown in the above edit?

Results from David's answer:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 108276092536515
                        [name] => Arnhem, Netherlands
                    )
                [1] => Array()
            )
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 108276092536515
                        [name] => Arnhem, Netherlands
                    )
                [1] => Array()
            )
    )
[2] => Array()

[3] => Array()

[4] => Array()
```

I've tried variations of `array_filter`, `array_map`, `array_values` and others like below:

```
 $locations = array_map( 'array_filter', find_array_values( $users, 'location' ));
```

But the structure seems to stay...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED ANSWER**

```
$matches = array();

function find_array_values($haystack, $needle)
{

    global $matches;
    $collection = array();

    foreach($haystack AS $key => $value)
    {
        if($key === $needle)
        {
            $matches[] = $value;
        }
        else if(is_array($value))
        {
           find_array_values($value, $needle);
        }
    }
}

find_array_values($array, 'location');
print_r($matches);
?>
```

This will work, but as I already said in the comments it's a bad practice since it uses the global keyword. If you implement this function as a method into a class, instead of using the global keyword you could use a class variable which would be a neat solution.

**OLD Answer**

```
function find_array_values($haystack, $needle)
{
    $collection = array();

    foreach($haystack AS $key => $value)
    {
        if($key === $needle)
        {
            $collection[] = $value;
        }
        else if(is_array($value))
        {
           $collection[] = find_array_values($value, $needle);
        }
    }

    return $collection;

}

echo "<pre>";
print_r(find_array_values($users, 'location'));
echo "</pre>";
```

Here you are. Just pass an array of your users into the function. The function will return an array of arrays of locations.

There's one restriction. The function will not search trough locations that are within locations.

Comment: Awesome! Almost what I was looking for ;) It seems to remove all other values, leaving the structure intact of the original array. `[6] => Array( [0] => Array( [0] => Array() [1] => Array( [id] => 115106888501966 [name] => Tilburg, Netherlands ) [2] => Array( [0] => Array() [1] => Array() )`. You wouldn't happen to have a solution for this as well by chance?

Comment: I just tried it for about 1 1/2 hours but I couldn't come off with a solution without using global variables which is bad practice. I hope someone else can put the last piece together because I'm now also very interested in this problem.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. Been at it since this morning so 5 hours now, would love for it to work. Btw, how did you do it using the 'bad practice'? For me bad practice doesn't matter as it's a one off project to combine the databases with the data into 1 after which all of this code would be dropped to create a real-time system. That last system is the one where security and good code practice will be coming in.

Comment: I updated my answer :) Have a look on it. I also added a suggestion for a better practice.

Comment: That is an awesome answer! :) Thank you very much indeed! (If I need to do something similar with real-time data I'll fix the bad practice)

Comment: why not using array_merge when calling your function recursively ?

Answer (score 0):

you can modify ur location part of your array like this

```
[location] => Array
        (
            [work]=> Array(
                 [id] => 108276092536515
                  [name] => Arnhem, Netherlands
             )
             [home] => Array(
                 [id] => 108276092536515
                  [name] => Arnhem, Somewhere else
             )
        )
```

if you modify your array like this then your function will return array of arrays for location

Comment: You do realise that when I mention 5000+ records (in this DB alone, more to come) that it's not an option to 'change' the location part right? Also, as seen from the code, this is Facebook data, in the structure it's stored as received from Facebook apps, therefore changing the location also wouldn't be up to me ;)